# Pull data for specific date time range #Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a datetime feild in Teradata having data as 1/01/2019 02:13:08 .
I need to pull data for specific time range such as between 1/01/2019 and 1/02/2019
and time interval between 9pm to 6 am like range between 1/01/2019 21:00:00 and 1/02/2019 6:00:00 .

How can this be achieved .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you only want records that were inserted with a time that is at night, between two dates. Night being defined as "between 9pm and 6am"

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
  datecol BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-02-01' AND
  NOT (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM datecol) BETWEEN 6 AND 21)
```

The first predicate gets all the data from the date range, and the second predicate **excludes** records that are between 6am and 9pm i.e. it excludes all the day time records leaving only the night time ones

If your query is simpler, that you really only literally want the records between 9pm on 2019-01-01 and 6am on 2019-02-01 then query that:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
  datecol BETWEEN '2019-01-01 21:00' AND '2019-02-01 06:00'
```

**Please also note that when you ask on SO, you have an international audience** and it's not clear from your post whether your dates are `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy`. I've assumed `dd/mm/yyyy` but you should perhaps **consider switching format to `yyyy-mm-dd` when you ask questions in future** as this is an ISO format that is not ambiguous. If your date format in your question is `mm/dd/yyyy` you will need to adjust my queries according to your needs because my queries are "all of january", but if you meant `mm/dd` then you're looking for "overnight from jan 1st to jan 2nd"